# localhost didn't send data --- node/express/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good day, I'm really new to node and mongodb and I really need help on why I am getting an empty response on the route

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();


const Profile = require('../models/profile');


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  Profile.find()
    .then(profiles => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: 'success',
        data: profiles
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: 'fail',
        message: err.message
      })
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't get an error, but the browser just times out, Profile.find() doesn't seem to work at all.

This is my schema, and I only expect the route to return an empty array, not a timeout

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Profile = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {type:String, trim: true, default: ''},
    lastName: {type:String, trim: true, default: ''},
    age: {type: Number, default: 0},
    team: {type:String, trim: true, default: ''},
    position: {type:String, trim: true, default: ''}
})



module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', Profile);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm curious about one thing If remove the `Profile.find()`, only leave the `res.json({confirmation: 'success',data: profiles})` in get method. Does it work?

Comment: You should create & `save` some data (Any docs inside `Profile`? Maybe the collection is really empty == without any document). 
Follow again the steps here (1. create schema / 2. compile model / 3. create doc (missing in your code) / 4. save doc (also missing)): https://mongoosejs.com/docs/

Comment: @JackYu without the Profile.find(), it sends ({confirmation: 'success'}), but without a data:  profiles

Comment: Thanks @Ezra Siton, I should've just gone through the docs right from the start...problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to specify the name of the collection at **mongoose.model()** as a third argument? Also did you connect to your database?